# popoverpresentviewcontroller with rectangle corner and without arrow

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipopovercontroller

I want a popover without rounded corners and with no arrow.

I have done the following code but it did not work:

//SerachPopViewController.swift

```
    //MARK: InitCoder
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //popover settings
    //popoverPresentationController!.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    //permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width:340,height:380)
}
```

//QueryTableViewController.swift

```
    @IBAction func searchFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

    let searchPopController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SerachPopViewController") as! SerachPopViewController
    searchPopController.serachPopDelegate = self
    searchPopController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    searchPopController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width:340,height:380)

    let popoverPresentationController = searchPopController.popoverPresentationController

    popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = self.view;
    popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0)
    popoverPresentationController!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection();
    self.presentViewController(searchPopController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am able to display popover view with arrow and rounded arrow.

Please help me to achieve:

- popup view with rectangle corner
- popup view without direction arrows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not 100% happy with [shawnynicole's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41793164/149008) answer because I realized the change from the rounded to the rectangular corners are notable/visible.

So I came up with this: subclass the view controller (in my case it was an `UINavigationController`) and override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and update corners there. This is better because corners change animation is not visible and it will be updated every time needed (on rotations, etc).

It works in iOS11 and probably should work on others versions too.

```
class PopoverNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: Int = -1

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let r = CGFloat(cornerRadius)
        if r >= 0 && view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius != r {
            view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = r
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Using the concept above, you can also set the corner radius in the completion parameter.

Swift 3

```
let popoverViewController: UIViewController = // Some view controller to be presented in a popover

// Set popover properties here...
// i.e. popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

present(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: {
     popoverViewController.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0

    // Additional code here
})
```

Comment: Thanks, best one. Works on iOS 10.3.3

Comment: Thank you very much ! you saved my day and you are my saviour

Comment: This breaks if the screen rotates. You need to set it each time the orientation changes.

Answer (score 7):

In iOS 11 its not possible to use @SHN solution for removing rounded corners. The corner radius is set to default value after viewWillAppear.

Radius must be set in viewDidAppear method

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but on iOS 11, if we rotate the device, the corner radius will come back. Don't know how to fix it for now.

Answer (score 4):

To get popover without arrow when you are initiating popover, use:

```
popover!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
```

For popover without corner radius, in the popover content view controller use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
    }
```

Comment: @SurajLokhande If it worked for you, can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why It does't work on my Simulator with iOS11.1 until trying setting backgroundColor.I added function viewWillTransition for rotating device.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    view.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    view.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO and thanks for answering.
To make it more useful to other users it helps to explain where the problems were with the original code and how yours is an improvement

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4**, in case you present your popover embedded in a navigation controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I do it in order to achieve such a functionality which works also on device rotation:

In the view controller that you set as a popover add the following code:

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
}

extension MyPopoverViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func popoverPresentationController(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverTo rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, in view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>) {
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }
```

Finally, set your popover's `delegate` to the instance of this view controller before presenting it:

```swift
...
popover.delegate = myPopoverViewController
present(myPopoverViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of these answers fix the OP's question about corner radius, but you can get the same effect by changing your presented view controller's top view's background to clear. Then just round the corners of the next top view to the desired amount (or not, if you want it to be a straight top).

I prefer this way because it gives you more WYSIWYG control over the presented view. For example, you can present a floating square by just centering a view in the view controller and presenting it.

Comment: I do not belive that is possible when you don't use `UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext` - do you have a sample of that working?